# Populate empty table with data from oter table based on dropdown list selection

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have 3 tables, `Tab1`, `Tab2` and `Tab3` containing data and an empty table `Tab`
The user can select in a drop-down list, `option1`, `option2` and `option3`.

On the selection from user the empty table `Tab` will be populated with the corresponding table.

For example, when the user selects `option2`, the `Tab` is populated with the data from `Tab2`; all the tables have the same size.

I could manage to use `INDIRECT` to add value for one cell but not to the complete table.
Have you any ideas, any easy formula for Excel 2007. I am not using VBA.

Comment: Are you tables in different Sheet? Do they all start at the same row?

Comment: This will be lot easier with VBA..

Comment: Wait wait, you want a drop down list that populates an array (from multiple sources) without using a macro? Have you tried a pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make your drop down values the name of your tables if possible. And assign a named range to the cell that contains the resulting dropdown value,such as `OptionPicked`.
In your empty range that is the same dimmensions as the three tables put this formula in every cell.

`INDEX(INDIRECT(OptionPicked &"[#All]"),ROW()-ROW($A$1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$1))`

This will work if the empty table `Tab` is not an actual excel table as formulas are not allowed in the headers of excel tables.

If you don't want to use the table names as the drop down choices you could build two lists that hold your `TableNames` and your `DropDownChoices` and have your drop down box refer to the list `=DropDownChoices` and the cell that contains that dropdown would still be named `OptionPicked`.
Then in every cell in the `Tab` "table" enter this formula

`=INDEX(INDIRECT(INDEX(TableNames,MATCH(OptionPicked,DropDownChoices,0)) &"[#All]"),ROW()-ROW($A$1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$1))`

[image]