# Excel drop down list to change data table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a drop down list to select sets of data from another sheet, but I'm a bit lost on how to do it

Basically, I have matrices with data that change according to different scenarios, and currently I'm doing CTRL+C and CTRL+V to evaluate the scenarios, but it would be amazing if I could just select the scenarios through a drop-down list (like optimistic, pessimistic and expected scenarios)

Thanks!

Update:
Imagine I have this data for scenario 1:

1 | 2

3 | 4

and this data for scenario 2:

2 | 2

1 | 4

Currently, if I want to change scenarios I'll just CTRL+C and CTRL+V those matrices into the main sheet, but I'd like to be able to select which matrix to show through a drop-down list

UPDATE: The user Michael Frank gave me an excellent option for doing this (with tables, but you can adapt it to use ranges too!). Here goes the link:

[Populate empty table with data from oter table based on dropdown list selection](https://superuser.com/questions/693376/populate-empty-table-with-data-from-oter-table-based-on-dropdown-list-selection)

Thanks mike!

Comment: You need to be more specific about the layout of your spreadsheet. Where are the matricies? Where are the scenarios? A screenshot would be helpful. Please edit your original question with additional details.

Comment: I see that you added information about what the matrices look like, but where are they located? Is each one on a separate sheet, or are they on the same sheet?

Comment: Is your question *How do I create a drop-down list in Excel?* Also please specify you excel version

Comment: Excel 2010, and it doesn't matter where they are located, I can move them to wherever it's best suited (within the same workbook, of course)

Comment: Look into `CHOOSE()`

Comment: Do you just want to make a *drop-down list*?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://superuser.com/questions/693376/populate-empty-table-with-data-from-oter-table-based-on-dropdown-list-selection