# Populate a range of cells in Excel from a drop down list that pulls from a choice of tables on a second sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, disclaimer, I am not as versed in Excel as I would like to be. But, I'm pretty sure what I'm trying to accomplish can be done. In fact, I think I found the solution to the problem I have, I just need to go one step further.

Here [is a similar question asked by a user some time ago](https://superuser.com/questions/693376/populate-empty-table-with-data-from-oter-table-based-on-dropdown-list-selection?newreg=ed87d6e223794b84a8aa867d8c03b438), and what he's asking for is exactly what I'm seeking, as well. However, in my case, the tables I want to populate from are located on a second sheet, and the table I want to populate and the drop down list is located on the first sheet.

A user by the name of Scheballs provided what appears to be a solution, but because my tables are located on the second sheet, the code he provides does not work, and I'm not at all knowledgeable about the codes and commands and how to manipulate them.

Here is the formula in question, which he recommends putting into every cell in the range I want to fill.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(INDEX(TableNames,MATCH(OptionPicked,DropDownChoices,0)) &"[#All]"),ROW()-ROW($A$1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$1))
```

For a visual aid, here is a screenshot of an my sheet 1:

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug9uf.png)

And here is a screenshot of a table from Sheet 2:

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOLVk.png)

I hope I have provided enough information for what I am trying to achieve, and I am more than happy to go into more detail if it is required. I'm hoping the solution is as simple as altering the formula so that it knows to pull from Sheet2, but if it needs to be more involved than that I'm ready and willing to learn.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you open to using power query? It's the textbook tool to use in this case, and it's relatively simple (Compared to the formula method), and much lighter on the calculations

Comment: I'm open to whatever method gets the job done. I'm willing to learn if you're willing to teach!

Comment: You're going to want to combine a tutorial about power query (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-101-008b3f46-5b14-4f8b-9a07-d3da689091b5 - note your data source is "from table") with https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/how-to-reference-a-named-range-in-power-query/